# Skip app for foreground when clicking on notification, without opening new

Tags: android, notifications

What I wanted to do was open the app by notification in two cases:

1. Case open app : Just pull background
2. Case closed app: Opens new app

The code that I have is the next:

```
NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

String title = context.getString(R.string.notification_title);
String message = context.getString(getNotificationText());
Bitmap largeIcon = getLargeBitmap();

NotificationCompat.Builder notification =
        (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(context).setContentTitle(title).setContentText(message)
       .setSmallIcon(getIcon()).setLargeIcon(largeIcon).setOngoing(true);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        intent.setAction("android.intent.action.MAIN");
        intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");


        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent);

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        notification.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    }
    manager.notify(NETWORK_STATUS_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification.build());
}
```

The problem I have is that the code is working on Android 5 and up, but does not work on Android : JELLY_BEAN and KITKAT .

Someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` to your intent :

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

From the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK) :

> When using this flag, if a task is already running for the activity you are now starting, then a new activity will not be started; instead, the current task will simply be brought to the front of the screen with the state it was last in.

Comment: On Android JELLY_BEAN and KITKAT, continued does not working! :(

Comment: why have you set `intent.setAction("android.intent.action.MAIN");` and `intent.addCategory` ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960459/re-open-background-application-via-notification-item